# XSLT - create new XML

Tags: xslt

I have one xml A and want to create a new xml B. The outer elements of B are different from A, but some of the child nodes are the same. I have written an XSL file but am struggling to get it right. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? How do I copy individual elements from A to B? The issue is, when the transformation happens, the text in A is copied to B. Looking at previous stack overflow questions, this is because there is an error in my xsl but I cant figure out what.

A:

```
<Request>
    <Source>
        <RequestorID Client="1" EMailAddress="test@test.com" Password="pwd"/>
        <RequestorPreferences Country="JP" Currency="jpy" Language="en">
            <RequestMode>SYNCHRONOUS</RequestMode>
        </RequestorPreferences>
    </Source>
    <RequestDetails>
        <SearchHotelPriceRequest>
            <ItemDestination DestinationCode="LON" DestinationType="city"/>
            <ItemCode>98i</ItemCode>
            <PeriodOfStay>
                <CheckInDate>2015-05-20</CheckInDate>
                <CheckOutDate>2015-05-21</CheckOutDate>
            </PeriodOfStay>
            <IncludePriceBreakdown/>
            <IncludeChargeConditions/>
            <Rooms>
                <Room Code="tb" NumberOfCots="0" NumberOfRooms="1">
                    <ExtraBeds/>
                </Room>
            </Rooms>
        </SearchHotelPriceRequest>
    </RequestDetails>
</Request>
```

B:

```
<WebRequest>
    <RequestDetails>
        <WebSearchHotelPriceRequest
                CallCentreClientUI="2577"
                Client="1"
                Country="JP"
                Currency="jpy"
                Language="en"
                LoginID="">
            <GcPriceOptions ShowDeduped="true"/>
            <ItemDestination DestinationCode="LON" DestinationType="city"/>
            <ItemName></ItemName>
            <ItemCode>98i</ItemCode>
            <EffectiveDate>2014-08-15</EffectiveDate>
            <StarRatingRange>
                <Min>0</Min>
                <Max>0</Max>
            </StarRatingRange>
            <PeriodOfStay>
                <CheckInDate>2015-05-20</CheckInDate>
                <CheckOutDate>2015-05-21</CheckOutDate>
            </PeriodOfStay>
            <IncludeChargeConditions/>
            <Rooms>
                <Room Code="tb" NumberOfRooms="1"></Room>
            </Rooms>
            <SiteId>008</SiteId>
        </WebSearchHotelPriceRequest>
    </RequestDetails>
</WebRequest>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="Request">
        <xsl:element name="WebRequest">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RequestDetails">
        <xsl:element name="RequestDetails">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SearchHotelPriceRequest">
        <xsl:element name="WebSearchHotelPriceRequest">
            <xsl:attribute name="CallCentreClientUI">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Client">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Country">UK</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Currency">GBP</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Language">EN</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="LoginID">100</xsl:attribute>

            <SiteId>001</SiteId>
            <EffectiveDate>01-01-99</EffectiveDate>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ItemDestination">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ItemCode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ItemName">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PeriodOfStay">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="IncludeChargeConditions">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Rooms">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Incorrect Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WebRequest>SYNCHRONOUS<RequestDetails>
<WebSearchHotelPriceRequest CallCentreClientUI="1" Client="1" Country="UK" Currency="GBP" Language="EN" LoginID="100">
<SiteId>001</SiteId>
<EffectiveDate>01-01-99</EffectiveDate>
<ItemDestination DestinationCode="LON" DestinationType="city"/>
<ItemCode>98i</ItemCode>
<PeriodOfStay>
<CheckInDate>2015-05-20</CheckInDate>
<CheckOutDate>2015-05-21</CheckOutDate>2015-05-202015-05-21</PeriodOfStay>
<IncludeChargeConditions/>
<Rooms>
<Room Code="tb" NumberOfCots="0" NumberOfRooms="1">
<ExtraBeds/>
</Room>
</Rooms>
</WebSearchHotelPriceRequest>
</RequestDetails>
</WebRequest>
```

Comment: Why are the values of pretty much all elements common to both input A and output B _not_ the same?

Comment: Xml B is just a sample.. It's the tags and values in A that are important.

Comment: Do not make it so hard for people to help you. Present an XML output that is exactly the result of transforming the input XML you show.

Comment: This is impossible to follow: for example, your XSLT has `WebSearchHotelPriceRequest/@Currency hardcoded as "GBP"; your requested output shows "USD". I **think** the correct value in your input is "jpy".

Comment: Fixed the values in B. As I said, its the elements I'm more interested in. If someone could tell me why the extra text (e.g. SYNCHRONOUS) is being erroneously copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making this much more complicated than it needs to be. The simplest way to copy elements (along with all they contain, i.e. "deep copy") is to use `xsl:copy-of`. Also, you don't need to use `xsl:element` if you know the name of the element; just output the element literally. Similarly, for `xsl:attribute` you can write it directly and - if necessary - use *attribute value template* to insert the value from the input.

Have a look at the following stylesheet as an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <WebRequest>
        <xsl:for-each select="Request/RequestDetails/SearchHotelPriceRequest">
            <RequestDetails>
                <WebSearchHotelPriceRequest
                    CallCentreClientUI="2577"
                    Client="2577"
                    Country="J"
                    Currency="USD"
                    Language="E"
                    LoginID="">
                    <GcPriceOptions ShowDeduped="true"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ItemDestination"/>
                    <ItemName></ItemName>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ItemCode"/>
                    <EffectiveDate>2014-08-15</EffectiveDate>
                    <StarRatingRange>
                        <Min>0</Min>
                        <Max>0</Max>
                    </StarRatingRange>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="PeriodOfStay | IncludeChargeConditions | Rooms"/>
                    <SiteId>008</SiteId>
                </WebSearchHotelPriceRequest>
            </RequestDetails>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </WebRequest>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is of course not exactly what you need, but I don't know which values go where.

> If someone could tell me why the extra text (e.g. SYNCHRONOUS) is
>   being erroneously copied?

Because you are using `xsl:apply templates` indiscriminately - and text nodes are copied by default using the built-in templates.